# S3 lauchctl error input/output. Boot doesn't mount S3 bucket

Tags: macos, mac, daemons

My script to mount an S3 bucket works fine, but mount at boot is not working. I tried launch daemons on macOS Sonoma, compiling with this plist. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.hfs34</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sshfs</string>
        <string>ubuntu@51.21.105.210:/</string>
        <string>/users/oscarristolfi/red34</string>
        <string>-o IdentityFile=&quot;/Users/oscarristolfi/.ssh/redchiavissh.pem&quot;</string>
        <string>-o reconnect,allow_other,volname=hfs-red2</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```